# UTF-8 problems in PostgreSQL

Tags: php, postgresql, unicode, utf-8

My database is UTF-8 (PostgreSQL). I saved 'TESTµTEST' into the database and it's OK. But when I selected this value from the database I saw 'TESTÂµTEST'.

Moreover, when I made a request `select * from tbl where f='TESTµTEST'`, I got this error:

> ERROR:  invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xb5.

Would you please give me any solutions?

Comment: Needs more info. What programming language and/or connection method? Show your code.

Comment: I use Php and pg_connect and pg_query.

Comment: `0xB5` is the Latin-1 encoding for "µ", it's not UTF-8.

Comment: What's the encoding for the tbl column?

Comment: @Jurgo, how can I check the encoding for the tbl column?

Comment: What db tool do you use? can't you see this in the structure of the table?

Comment: My tip (based on @decereé's observation) is that your PHP files (therefore strings to be inserted) are latin-1 encoded.  Be sure that those are also UTF8'd.

Comment: @Jurgo Encodings are set database-wide, not per-column. Sophy, please run `\l` from `psql` and paste the line for your database so your DB encoding is certain. Alternately you can run `SELECT d.datname, pg_catalog.pg_encoding_to_char(d.encoding) as "Encoding" FROM pg_database d WHERE datname = 'my_db_name_here';` which will work from any client.

Comment: Also, please show your PostgreSQL version.

Answer (score 3):

That error shows that you are trying to decode latin-1 text as if it were utf-8. Most likely your `client_encoding` setting in PHP doesn't match the encoding of the data you're actually sending.

The string "TESTÂµTEST" is produced by encoding data from Unicode to a utf-8 byte sequence, then decoding it as latin-1. You can see this in psql:

```
regress=# select convert_from(convert_to('TESTµTEST','utf-8'),'latin-1');
 convert_from 
--------------
 TESTÂµTEST
```

If the PostgreSQL database were `utf-8` it would convert `latin-1` input to `utf-8` if `client_encoding` was correctly set to `latin-1`. If `client_encoding` is incorrectly set to `utf-8` and you send `latin-1` encoded data, PostgreSQL will refuse to accept it with the message:

```
invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xb5
```

... which is what happens when you run that `SELECT` you showed. So - I'd say your client is set to `client_encoding = 'utf-8'` but your PHP scripts are actually sending `latin-1` data. I expect that's because, as @dezso says, you're editing your PHP scripts with a text editor that's using the `latin-1` encoding.

To find out which encoding PHP is using, use a PHP database connection to run `SHOW client_encoding;`.

To show the database encoding, run:

```
SELECT d.datname, pg_catalog.pg_encoding_to_char(d.encoding) as "Encoding" 
FROM pg_database d WHERE datname = 'my_db_name_here';
```

Oh, another possibility is that Apache (or whatever) expects your PHP scripts to be `utf-8` encoded, but they're actually `latin-1` encoded files.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same error when copying tables into PostgreSQL 9.1 which contained the same symbol (tables from the [standard nutrient database v26](http://www.ars.usda.gov/Services/docs.htm?docid=23602)). I recreated the database with the new encoding, but I also had to specify the appropriate [locale and template](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/BANLkTikSPsF7-Vu6KSwqKcYzK8O5hBZPvw@mail.gmail.com).

```
CREATE DATABASE testdb
  WITH OWNER = postgres
  ENCODING = 'LATIN1'
  LC_COLLATE = 'eng_canada.28591'
  LC_CTYPE = 'eng_canada.28591'
  TEMPLATE = template0;
```